# Composer error installing laravel-cors

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I tried to install laravel-cors

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

It installed successfully or so I thought, but then when I went to publish the config I get this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>         Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Composer\Autoload\includeFile() (previously declared in /www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:410) in /www/config/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 413

I have tried removing laravel-cors and I still get this error. I have dumped autoload as well. What am I missing?

Larval 5.2 | PHP 5.6.17

Comment: How can i track this error down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When i typed

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

i was in a sub directory. so composer then installed it and the dependencies in a sub directory which is why i was getting that error. If you look closely you can see that it was installing in config

```
/www/config/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:413 
/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:410
```

Just needed to pay better attention to detail.