# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Composer\Autoload\includeFile()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

The following problem appeared after installing this:

```
composer require merujan99 / laravel-video-embed: dev-master
```

I got this error message:

```
 @php artisan package:discover
 PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Composer\Autoload\includeFile()(previously declared in /var/www/cain/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:442)  in /var/www/cain/config/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 445 
 Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

when i delete the file

```
vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
```

or

```
config/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
```

and then I put:

```
composer install
```

I get this new error message

```
@php artisan package:discover
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit7004d442aef5fba74e99655522408450, because the name is already in use in /var/www/cain/config/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 5
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

this is very weird, I have 2 computers, in the first

> (Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27,php 7.2)

one I did not have problems when installing the extension and when doing "composer install" I did not get any error and laravel works normal

in the second computer

> (Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04, php 7.2)

when cloning the project through git I get that error

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` help you?

Comment: nop i get this error:  [link]   PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit7004d442aef5fba74e99655522408450, because the name is already in use in /var/www/cain/config/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 5
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: Delete vendor folder then `composer install`?

Comment: similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064067/composer-error-installing-laravel-cors
check what is in the config directory.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto return to the same:  PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ...

Comment: @sj-i that answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064067/composer-error-installing-laravel-cors) is not very clear

Comment: @jhoss, can you explain why install composer in two different folders?

Comment: No, they are not in two folders, they are in two different computers

Comment: @jhoss, no. Composer installation in two folders `vendor` and `config/vendor`. Have you ever installed `composer install ...` in the config folder?

Comment: Hmm... I get this error when I run phpunit with coverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the current directory is the right place when you use the composer command.
Use the composer command in /var/www/cain/ instead of /var/www/cain/config/, if what you want to do is adding a package to the project in /var/www/cain/.
Probably you have multiple composer installations in /var/www/cain/ and /var/www/cain/config/.
Remove the wrongly installed files from /var/www/cain/config/, if it is there.

Comment: delete the vendor folder and the composer.json and composer.lock config files and everything works normally, thanks